# How can I make a search bar with an <input> button open a domain if entered?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I currently have this code for a custom DuckDuckGo search bar:

```
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get" id="ddg-search">
    <div class="div-block-4">
        <input autofocus="true" class="text-field-3 hero-search-bar w-input" data-name="q" id="field-3" maxlength="256" name="q" placeholder="Search DuckDuckGo" type="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

It automatically opens the URL `https://duckduckgo.com/?q={{SEARCH}}` when you enter text in the box and press the enter key.

How could I make this bar go to a domain if one is entered? Optimally, it wouldn't validate the domain, just if it sees a string in the pattern `xxxx.*` with no spaces, it would open that page in a new tab.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is by capturing the submit event of the form, analyze the input value and when it is a domain, open a new window with the domain and cancel the submit by returning false. In case of not being a valid domain, let the form proceed as usual by returning true.

Your html:

```
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get" onsubmit="return decideWhatToDo()" id="ddg-search">
    <div class="div-block-4">
        <input autofocus="true" class="text-field-3 hero-search-bar w-input" data-name="q" id="field-3" maxlength="256" name="q" placeholder="Search DuckDuckGo" type="text">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Your javascript:

```
function decideWhatToDo() {  
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('field-3').value;

  if (isDomain(inputValue)) {
    // the form won't be sent and a new window will open requesting the domain    
    if (!startsWithProtocol(inputValue)) {
      inputValue = 'http://' + inputValue;
    }

    window.open(inputValue, '_blank');
    return false;
  } 

  // Proceed to send the form as usual
  return true;
}

function startsWithProtocol(value) {
  return /^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)/.test(value);
}

function isDomain(value) {
  return /^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$/.test(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! This is working perfectly for any link you enter which is prefixed with a protocol like `http://`, but when a URL is entered without one, such as `example.com` vs `https://example.com`, it redirects to the base domain of the hosted site followed by /{entered URL}. Is there a way to redirect domains even when entered without a protocol? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are right, browser is interpreting it as a relative path. I'm going to change the script so it adds 'http://' as default protocol in case the value of the input field doesn't have one.

Comment: Script has been updated, watch out with variable inputValue, now is declared with 'let' instead of 'const'

Comment: @Brendan Please take into consideration to accept one of the answers. It rewards the people answering questions and it helps other users to find the most fitted solution to their problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So one way to handle it is to use an if condition and check the string against a RegExp that recognizes domain names.

Here's a nifty one you can use:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+/
```

I assume you don't need help getting the value from your text field or the actual redirection. However, if you needed more help, comment below and I'll post a more complete answer. The code below should help you get to where you want:

```js
var domainRegExp = /[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+/

var pass = domainRegExp.test('test.com')
var fail = domainRegExp.test('test')

console.log(pass, 'pass')
console.log(fail, 'fail')
```

So as you can see the value inside the 'pass' variable is true, and 'fail' is false.